# Static template member function for template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I have a template class and a template member function:

```
template<class T1>
struct A{
    template<class T2>
    static int f(){return 0;}
};
```

I want to specialize for a case when `T1` and `T2` are the same,

For example, define the case `A<T>::f<T>` for any `T`.

but I can't find the combination of keywords to achieve this.

**How can I partially (?) specialize a combination of template class and a template static function?**

---

These are my *unsuccessful* attempts, and the error messages:

1) Specialize inside the class: `fatal error: cannot specialize a function 'f' within class scope`)

```
template<class T1>
struct A{
    template<class T2>
    static int f(){return 0;}

    template<>
    static int f<T1>(){return 1;}

};
```

2) Specialize outside the class "simultaneously": `fatal error: cannot specialize a member of an unspecialized template`

```
template<class T>
void A<T>::f<T>(){return 1;}
```

3) Specialize using `template<>`: `fatal error: too few template parameters in template redeclaration`

```
template<> template<class T>
void A<T>::f<T>(){return 1;}
```

4) Invert the order: `fatal error: cannot specialize (with 'template<>') a member of an unspecialized template`

```
template<class T> template<>
void A<T>::f<T>(){return 1;}
```

5) Specialize the whole class (based on the error of attempt 3): `fatal error: class template partial specialization does not specialize any template argument; to define the primary template, remove the template argument list`

```
template<class T> 
struct A<T>{
    template<>
    static int f<T>(){return 1;}
};
```

6) Specialize the class but not the function (?): `fatal error: too few template parameters in template redeclaration
template<> template<class T1>`

```
template<> template<class T>
int A<T>::f(){return 0;}
```

I used `clang 3.5 C++14` to generate the error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot partially specialize a function.

You can forward the work to another type:

```
template<class T1>
struct A;

template<class T1, class T2>
struct A_helper {
  static int f() {
    return A<T1>::f_simple<T2>();
  }
};
template<class T>
struct A_helper<T,T> {
  static int f() {
    return A<T>::f_special();
  }
};

template<class T1>
struct A{
  template<class T2>
  static int f(){return A_helper<T1,T2>::f()}
  template<class T2>
  static int f_simple(){return 0;}
  static int f_special(){return -1;}
};
```

or, more simply, with no `A_helper`:

```
template<class T1>
struct A{
  template<class T2>
  static int f(){return f2<T2>(std::is_same<T1,T2>{});}
  template<class T2>
  static int f2(std::true_type){
    static_assert(std::is_same<T1,T2>{}, "bob!");
    return -1;
  }
  template<class T2>
  static int f2(std::false_type){return -1;}
};
```

you can use tag dispatching.

Another approach:

```
template<class T>struct tag{};

template<class T1>
struct A{
  template<class T2>
  static int f(){return f2(tag<T2>{});}
  template<class T2>
  static int f2(tag<T2>) {return 0;}
  static int f2(tag<T1>) {return -1;}
};
```

where we directly dispatch on the type of `T2`.